# Replace string in SQL Select using exact match

Tags: sql, oracle, select, replace

I am using

```
 SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(Status,'O','New'),'C','Closed') as STATUS,
```

in Oracle SQL Select

The problem is that my table has both:
'C'
and 
'Closed'

So it is actually replacing 'C' with 'Closed' and replacing 'Closed' with 'Closedlosed'

How do I get it to replace only when entire field matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to use regular expression to match only `C` character and nothing else:

```
WITH
  my_data AS
  (SELECT 'Closed' AS status FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 'C' AS status FROM dual)
SELECT
    regexp_replace(status, '^C$', 'Closed') AS rep_status
FROM
    my_data
;
```

Check at SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/19247

**Can you provide sample data?**